# Create Zooming Box

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a website and I've been trying to create something which will open new content when clicked on, somewhat like Facebook has on the pictures: You click, Get a window with the picture and text area for commenting. I'm specifically trying to avoid popups because I don't find them very neat.

Does anybody know how i could create this/ have any tutorials? Is this extremely complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at jquery ui:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid a popup. The only difference is that using a javascript framework like jquery you can have a beautiful popup.

So use the jquery dialog box to display the image and textbox for commenting. Using ajax you can save the comment and exit the dialog box. The trick is to make good use of css and opacity on the dialog box.